# Angular2 show all form group validation errors

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am building a deep nested form with Angular2 and FormGroup, currently I have a form such as in a parent controller:

```
this.orderForm = this.fb.group({

customerSelectForm: this.fb.group({ // create nested formgroup to pass to child
        selectTypeahead: ['', 
                            Validators.required],
        })
})
```

Then in a child component I have:

```
<div class="form-group" [formGroup]="customerSelectForm" *ngIf="customerSelectForm">
        <label for="oh-custaccount">Customer Account #</label>

    <input class="form-control" type="text" 
    formControlName="selectTypeahead"
    (focusout)=someFunction() />

    <p *ngIf="customerSelectForm.controls.selectTypeahead.errors?.required">
    Number required!</p>
</div>
```

Now this child template works fine, and renders an error on screen if there is no input inside the text box. I then back in the parent controller have a submit button:

```
<button type="submit" class=" btn btn-success" [disabled]="orderForm?.invalid">Submit</button>
```

Again, this works as expected, and only is enabled after an input is registered in the selectTypeahead input.

Now due to the large nature of this form, I want to have a display next to the submit button, that lists all form elements, which are currently failing. I did try rendering:

```
{{orderForm.errors}}
```

But this stayed as "null" even when my form was invalid, how would I list all inputs from orderFrom that have currently not passed/matched their corresponding validation rules?

Comment: take a look at this link it removes all the code from the html and places it in the ts files https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/AngularConcepts/blob/master/src/app/template-driven/template-driven.component.ts

Comment: Yea, so basically I need to subscribe to the form, when its changed, force all data through a validation, return errors to each component, then I can also return all errors as one to the template as a summary?

Comment: I have decided to create a service, each component will connect to an observable there, if an input has a validation failure, it will report to this service, then I can subscribe to its result and view all current errors, will post a working plunker soon,

Comment: If `{{orderForm.errors}}` says null when it's invalid you have some other issue.

Comment: Thanks, I now know the root form errors property is now related to the actual form layout itself, other than validation errors.

Comment: @crooksey did you manage to create this service? If yes could you post this as answer, I am looking for exactly the same scenario as you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @bruno in the end I used an angular form array and nested each form component in its own controller, works very well.

Answer (score 29):

I think you have to recursively visit the descendants controls of your form to obtain all errors.

```ts
getAllErrors(form: FormGroup | FormArray): { [key: string]: any; } | null {
    let hasError = false;
    const result = Object.keys(form.controls).reduce((acc, key) => {
        const control = form.get(key);
        const errors = (control instanceof FormGroup || control instanceof FormArray)
            ? this.getAllErrors(control)
            : control.errors;
        if (errors) {
            acc[key] = errors;
            hasError = true;
        }
        return acc;
    }, {} as { [key: string]: any; });
    return hasError ? result : null;
}
```

Then in your template

```html
<!--
  NOTE: This is just for displaying the result of the method
  You should replace the `<pre><code>` with whatever your snippet is like
-->
<pre><code>{{ getAllErrors(orderForm) | json }}</code></pre>
```

Comment: Perfect! Works great. Thanks

Comment: This solution does not return the error on the form itself but only on all FormControls and their descendants.